# Logout user after closing the browser

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, authentication, asp.net-web-api2

In my angular app,  I add the angular authentication From here
http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/09/angularjs-token-authentication-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/

I keep the user with  `localStorageService`

My save user code is:

```
 localStorageService.set('authorizationData', { token: response.access_token, userName: response.userName, refreshToken: response.refresh_token, is_admin: response.is_admin || response.is_admin == 'true', useRefreshTokens: true });
```

My Problem is that the browser keep the user until the token expired

How can I remove the localStorageService On closing the browser.

(Like cookie with no expire date)

Comment: use `sessionStorage` instead

Answer (score 0):

First detect the browser close which is by `$window.onbeforeunload`,then delete the localstorage.In case of a service,register `$window.onbeforeunload` in the angular.run lifecycle. Below is just an example.

```
angular.module('app', [])
      .controller('exitController', function($scope, $window) {
        $scope.onExit = function() {
         $localStorage.$reset();//it will delete all the data from localstorage.
        };

       $window.onbeforeunload =  $scope.onExit;
      });
```

Comment: This will log you out regardless of whether you have multiple tabs open.